# Strange MultiBinding StringFormat issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this XAML

```
<MultiBinding  StringFormat=" {0}{1}/{2}">
   <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthHost" />
   <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthWebsiteName" />
   <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="tbxAuthServicesAddress" />
</MultiBinding>
```

When I try change " {0}{1}/{2}" into "{0}{1}/{2}" so no leading space there and then Visual Studio gives this error:

**Error 3   The text '{1}/{2}' is not allowed after the closing '}' of a MarkupExtension expression. Line 116 Position 56.**

How I can fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Check in case you have a **space** after `{0}` ?

Comment: Hi! I don't have it 100%

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can fix this by putting `{}` at the front of the string format.

```
StringFormat="{}{0}{1}/{2}"
```

The [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) does a particularly bad job of explaining the format.

If you look at the page on the [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx) it explains that an opening curly bracket at the beginning denotes a markup extension (e.g. Binding), and `{0}{1}/{2}` is not a valid markup extension. It doesn't explain that not having it as the first character also works.

Comment: I'm trying to find my reference, but I remember reading it somewhere.